# Can't get Hazelcast to work in Docker Swarm

Tags: tomcat, docker, hazelcast, docker-swarm

I've been trying to get Hazelcast set up in a Docker swarm running Amazon EC2 for use as a Tomcat session copier (fallback because Amazon ELB's sticky session settings are refusing to work, if anyone's following my other question :P), and I'm trying to use the Hazelcast Tomcat sessions manager (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager).

I have 3 EC2 nodes, on which Docker Swarm is running (set up with Docker for AWS) with one instance of Tomcat running on each node.

I can't get the Hazelcast on each Tomcat instances to talk to each other. multicast doesn't work at all and TCP/IP results in constant refused connections even though everything is set up properly.

Here's the error output from tomcat when attempting to use TCP/IP and manually specifying the IP addresses:

```
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.934 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.null [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.3] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [172.31.23.183, 172.31.8.28, 172.31.37.34]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.934 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.null [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.3] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.936 WARNING [main] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.null [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.3] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.939 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.null [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.3] Picked [10.255.0.5]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.949 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Hazelcast 3.8.3 (20170704 - 10e1449) starting at [10.255.0.5]:5701
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.949 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:13.949 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.187 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Backpressure is disabled
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.702 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Creating TcpIpJoiner
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.865 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Starting 2 partition threads
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.866 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.877 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [10.255.0.5]:5701 is STARTING
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.914 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.8.28:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.915 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.8.28:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.8.28:5702]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.915 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.8.28]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.916 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.37.34:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.917 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-4] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.23.183:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.917 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.8.28:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.917 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.8.28:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.8.28:5701]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.917 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.8.28]:5701 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.918 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.37.34:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.37.34:5701]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.918 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-3] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.37.34]:5701 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.918 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-4] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.23.183:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.23.183:5701]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.918 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-4] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.23.183]:5701 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.918 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-2] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.8.28:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.919 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-2] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.8.28:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.8.28:5703]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.919 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-2] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.8.28]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.921 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.23.183:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.922 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.23.183:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.23.183:5702]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.922 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.23.183]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.923 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.37.34:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.924 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.37.34:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.37.34:5703]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.924 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.37.34]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.925 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.23.183:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.926 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.23.183:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.23.183:5703]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.926 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-1] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.23.183]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.930 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-8] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Connecting to /172.31.37.34:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.932 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-8] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Could not connect to: /172.31.37.34:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.31.37.34:5702]
25-Jul-2017 16:41:14.932 INFO [hz.SESSION-REPLICATION-INSTANCE.cached.thread-8] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [172.31.37.34]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
25-Jul-2017 16:41:15.930 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] Cluster version set to 3.8
25-Jul-2017 16:41:15.931 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3]
Members [1] {
Member [10.255.0.5]:5701 - 7995c688-0236-49b2-9894-53873cf5dc49 this
}
25-Jul-2017 16:41:15.955 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null [10.255.0.5]:5701 [dev] [3.8.3] [10.255.0.5]:5701 is STARTED
```

Comment: are you using any service discovery like zookeeper, etcd within deployment scripts or behind docker swarm?

Comment: No, I'm not running anything like that

Comment: What I see from the log is cluster members are not on the same network interface, Hazelcast supports AWS ECS with discovery. I can recommend that, also, you can deploy with compose file adding a discovery service like zookeeper in deployment for both HZ client and member. For AWS discovery you may refer to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws.

Comment: Looked into hazelcast-aws but dismissed it as the configuration looks very intimidating... also it appears it requires host networking mode to work, which Docker swarm mode is not compatible with.

Comment: It is not currently official AFAIK, but you may check https://github.com/bitsofinfo/hazelcast-docker-swarm-discovery-spi. regards